# default stock 2 and default source 1

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I'm facing a problem with only one product.

when I put Quantity 1 in Default Source. It increase by 1 in default stock it's become 2.

when i put it 0 become 0 on both Default Source and default stock.[image]

the rest of products it's ok, Except this product.

I'm using magento 2.4.2

Answer (score 0):

Source is ID of source provider and default stock source is 1 and it should be the same for all products assigned the the same website.

Stock - qty of products in stock and assigned to the stock source.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I don't understand why when I assign quantity for this product become +1 .
1 become 2 , 2 become 3 ...

Comment: Can you provide more details, maybe with screens to understand. This is really strange. Maybe you have customization or extension which increase qty to 1 from entered. Magento EE has Reservation logic, but i'm not sure if it's affect to.